# Is there a long method operation for modulo if mod or % is not a supported function/operator?

Tags: modulo, operation, blueprism

This is related to the Zeller's Congruence algorithm where there is a requirement to use Modulo to get the actual day of an input date. However, in the software I'm using which is Blueprism, there is no modulo operator/function that is available and I can't get the result I would hope to get.

In some coding language (Python, C#, Java), Zeller's congruence formula were provided because mod is available.

Would anyone know a long method of combine arithmetic operation to get the mod result?

From what I've read, mod is the remainder result from two numbers. But 
181 mod 7 = 6 and 181 divided by 7 = 25.857.. the remainder result are different.

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers to this.

1. If you have a floor() or int() operation available, then a % b is:

   a - floor(a/b)*b

(revised to incorporate [Andrzej Kaczor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5779258/andrzej-kaczor)'s comment, thanks!)

2. If you don't, then you can iterate, each time subtracting b from a until the remainder is less than b. At that point, the remainder is a % b.

Comment: A little better equation for that might be a%b=a - floor(a/b)*b, because of precision issues.